# How can I log "real" Http Headers on WebClient

Tags: spring, netty, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I'm currently using `ExchangeFilterFunction` to log all Headers that come inside the `ClientRequest` instance and I'm accessing to them doing `request.headers()`.

After my filter is executed, the `HttpClient` underneath is adding certain headers such as the `Accept-Encoding` one, thus not getting logged, as they never get added to the `ClientRequest` instance.

My filter looks like this:

```
public class WebClientLoggingFilter implements ExchangeFilterFunction {

    @Override
    public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(final ClientRequest clientRequest, final ExchangeFunction next) {
         return Mono.just(clientRequest)
               .doOnNext(request -> log(request.headers().toString()))
               .flatMap(next::exchange)
               .doOnNext(clientResponse -> logData(clientRequestData, message, clientResponse));
  } 
}
```

This filter logs everything inside `ClientRequest` headers, but then `HttpClient` does its magic, which never arrives at the ClientRequest, even after the response is back. [Example of code](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/master/src/main/java/reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClientConnect.java#L538) from Netty.

Is there any other way I can do the logging so I can get access to what it's truly being sent through the network?

Answer (score 11):

Instead of using a filter, I'd recommend utilising the standard loggers by adding these lines to your `resources/application.properties`:

```
spring.http.log-request-details=true
logging.level.org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions=TRACE
```

However, by default, this will still show headers as `{headers masked}` (as they may contain sensitive data). To enable header logging for a client, you must explicitly enable it on each `WebClient` as follows:

```
return WebClient
        .builder()
        .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder().codecs(c ->
                c.defaultCodecs().enableLoggingRequestDetails(true)).build()
        )
        .build()
        //carry on using the webclient as normal
```

You'll then get output similar to the following:

```
HTTP POST https://a.com/ea, headers=[Content-Type:"application/json", Accept:"application/json", Authorization:"Bearer token blah"]
```

Comment: This approach looks promising. Would it be any way of customizing the logging format? we need a very specific format. 
Also, can I somehow get access to the bodies?

Answer (score 4):

The configuration property to use has changed to:

```
  spring.codec.log-request-details=true
```